# Go YouTube API: What use instead of liveBroadcasts.control method to display slate?

Tags: go, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Re golang YouTube API, I would like to know what calls to perform to make a slate image appear in the middle of a livestream. Reading the API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started), it's suggested that the "control" operation is used to achieve this, however, this operation is not supported by the API in the latest version. I did find this functionality in a prior version (v0.3.2); why would this have been removed and what is the replacement ?
Cheers,
Saxon

Comment: File a feature request to the maintainers of [Google APIs Client Library for Go](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client) on its [own issue tracker site](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client). SO is not Google support.

Comment: @stvar my first point of call was actually the issue tracker for the respective repository. An engineer asked me to post here instead, including the "youtube-livestreaming-api" tag in my post, which google engineers supposedly monitor....

Comment: See here also https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/support

Comment: The [answer you got](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/1240), @Saxon Milton, says (quote): *I am not too familiar with this API. I suggest reaching out with one of the items listed on the Live Streaming API Support Page.* I'm also recommending to do exactly that: reach out to Google directly since (again) SO is not Google support.

Comment: See a bit down, @Saxon Milton, on [that page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/support) you quoted: ***[Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) Something wrong? Send us a bug report!*** and ***Issue Tracker: [File a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) / [Request a feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) / [See open issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600)***.

Comment: @stvar yes, one of those items is also SO. Besides, this is not a bug report or feature request (at least not yet). I'm simply asking how I might perform an operation; providing notes on what steps I did take to investigate the whereabouts of the functionality. It would be a stretch to call this a bug report or feature request imo.

Comment: @stvar I've looked at stack overflow post guidelines, and I can't seem to find in what ways this post deviates. Please inform me if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The API behavior you're experiencing is documented officially, as per this excerpt from the official specification of the [`liveBroadcasts.control`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/control) API endpoint:

> **Note:** The `liveBroadcasts.control` method has been deprecated and will stop working on or after 1 October 2020. After that date, all calls to this method will return a forbidden (403) error, and the method will later be completely removed.
>
> Clients can still implement their own slating by adding an overlay to the video sent to YouTube’s ingestion servers. [See deprecation announcement](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/revision_history#release_notes_09_21_2020).

There's nothing you can do about that, *but only to file a feature request directly to Google* in the attempt to make the company reinstate the feature that it retracted from the current API.

In my opinion (which is based on the experience of several years of monitoring the SO tags [youtube-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-api), [youtube-data-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) and [youtube-livestreaming-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-livestreaming-api)), waiting for Google to respond to you here on SO is waste of time. Just do what I already recommended you to do in my comments posted under your question above: reach out directly to Google (through the company's [official issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)) for to obtain official accounts from the company's staff.